# How to open another app using its package is through web-intent in ionic and send and receive data

Tags: ionic-native, webintents

I did all configuration and able to open another app but not able to send and receive data,
but not able to send data and receive data,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Explain your expected behavor and what error occours.